# Recreating postman post request in HTTParty with AWS signature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, httparty

I have a custom API that needs to pass in an AWS access key, secret key, and region. I'm able to generate results from the post requests in Postman when I place these credentials in Authorization headers under AWS signature type. But I'm not sure the proper syntax to pass in for HTTParty in ruby.

This is my current request expression:

```
response = HTTParty.post(BASE_URL, :body => data.to_json, :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

All examples I see are Authorization passing in a token. But in postman I'm passing the access key, secret key and region. Do I need to generate a token before this? If so, how?

Comment: Postman has a feature to represent your request in Ruby code with Net::HTTP. I recommend posting the example it provides. (with the sensitive information redacted) That way this question becomes more narrow. (the task then is to convert a Net::HTTP call to an HTTParty call, which should be straightforward for most Rubyists and require no special AWS knowledge)

Comment: I've found the code snippet but the signature is already generated. I'm looking for the step to generate the signature.

Comment: Can you share more information about how it's done in Postman? Steps to reproduce, screenshot (if necessary), etc. Happy to take a look at it but starting from scratch would be hard for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's done in Postman. There seems to be a middle step between submitting the AWS credentials and having a signature. It's seems to be automatic. But I'm trying to figure out the middle step of how that signature is created.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I meant explaining how you set up the request in postman, not how postman actually generates the signature. That way I can reproduce your setup and request structure.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a ruby gem for this, aws-sigv4 (assuming that's the version you need in your case, double check) that allows you to pass in your credentials, region, and request to create a signature. It returns a hash of headers that act as its signature, which you can pass to HTTParty with the rest of the request details.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Sigv4/Signer.html